# Shortcut/key combination to change tool options

Tags: shortcuts, krita

Is there a shortcut/key combination to change tool options?

e.g. when using the brush, pressing/holding a key and switching to weighted smoothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a way to do this, looking around shouldn't have taken long for you to figure this out either.

1. Click Settings
2. Go to "Configure Shortcuts"
3. Type in (search) "smoothing"
4. Define the keys you want to use for each type of smoothing.

I don't think you can press and hold keys to do this (might be able to script it in somehow) but these work as toggle buttons to switch between each type of smoothing.

Comment: It works indeed! But you can only change to smoothing, you can't toggle it, but you could add a second shortcut for disabled smoothing so it's ok I guess...

Comment: @xpy yes, I recommend you bring it up for discussion in the krita forums. http://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=136